# React - issue with image when creating new message in a chat

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm looking for a solution to this bug for long days...
I'm new with React.

I have a chat. We could send messages, images, videos, images with message etc.

I've done a short video to show you the issue because it's hard to explain (as you can see with the title).
See the video here : https://vimeo.com/336108493

The code to render an image :

```
const renderImage = (item, popup) => {
        return (
            <div className={"message-image"}>
                <img className={"img-fluid curs-pointer"} src={item['media'].cachePath} alt={"Image"} onClick={() => this.setState({ openLightboxMessageId:  item.id  })}/>
                {this.state.openLightboxMessageId === item.id && (
                    <Lightbox
                        mainSrc={item['media'].cachePath}
                        onCloseRequest={() => this.setState({ openLightboxMessageId:false})}
                        reactModalStyle={{overlay : {zIndex:"1040"}}}

                    />
                )}
            </div>
        );
    };
```

When uploading an image, we create a new line in DB, and then we retrieve all lines in the component and we push items in an array :

```
this.state.messages.map((item, i) => {
        items.push(
            <li className={"media message mb-3"+ (item.userId == user.id ? ' message-current_user':'') + (item.isAdminMessage ? ' message-admin':'')} >

                {item.userId != user.id &&
                    <div className="mr-3">
                        <Avatar user={item} isAdmin={item.isAdminMessage}/>
                    </div>
                }
                <div className={"media-body "}>
                    {renderContent(item)}
                    <div className={item.userId == user.id ?'text-right':'text-left'}>
                        <small className={"text-muted"}>{item['firstname']} {item['lastname']}. - {moment(item['createdAt']).fromNow()}</small>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {item.userId == user.id &&
                <div className="ml-3">
                    <Avatar user={item} isAdmin={item.isAdminMessage}/>
                </div>
                }
            </li>
        );
    });
```

Does someone know from where is coming this kind of browser cache issue ?
Instead of adding an image after another one, if we send a text message, there is no issue.

Thanks for your help

Comment: I think instead of making a request each time a user uploads an image, to get all the images from db, send data to db and add the current image to the array.

Comment: I think it's already what it is doing.  
In **componentWillReceiveProps** we have :  
`if (nextProps.created !== this.props.created){  
            this.updateMessagesList([nextProps.created], false);  
        }`  
In **updateMessagesList** function we are doing :  
`updateMessagesList = (newMessages, isOlder) => {
        const oldMessages = this.state.messages;
        const messages = isOlder ? oldMessages.concat(newMessages): newMessages.concat(oldMessages);
        this.setState({ messages: messages });
    };`